# Can't get links to work correctly for bootstrap html data-content in popover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am trying to put html in the bootstrap popover and the content shows nicely but when I click on my links inside the popover it just goes to the parent 'OpenRecent' method on the anchor tag that triggers the popover. You can see below in the data-content html the different ways I try to call the function I want. How can I achieve this?

```
<ul id="RecentSearches" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked well" data-bind="foreach: CurrentItems">
        <li>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox inline" data-bind="value: $data.TransId,
                                                                          checked: $root.ItemsSelected"/>
                <a href="#"
                   data-bind="text: $data.Description + '-' + $data.County,
                              attr: 
                              { 
                                id: $data.TransId,
                                'data-title': $data.Description
                              },
                              click: $root.OpenRecent"
                   data-trigger="hover"
                   rel="popover"
                   data-html="true"
                   data-content="<a data-bind='click: $parent.Print.bind($data)'>Print</a> |
                                 <a data-bind='click: app.RecentSearches.Print.bind($data)'>Print 2</a>
                                 <a data-bind='click: $parent.Email'>Email</a> |
                                 <a data-bind='click: $parent.SaveToPDF'>PDF</a> |
                                 <a data-bind='click: $parent.SavetToCSV'>CSV</a>">
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML is your `data-content` will not have been bound by Knockout, as it was added dynamically later.

One option is to add a way to identify the links (class) and then use an [unobstrusive approach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) to adding an event handler.

```
$("ul").on("click", ".print", function(event) {
     var context = ko.contextFor(this);
     context.$root.Print(context.$data);
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

I am not sure why your `OpenRecent` function is getting called. It appears to me that bootstrap creates the popover outside of the element that it is triggered on. So, this would not be a parent of the popover. If you are still having an issue with that part, then maybe you could get it working in jsFiddle.

Here is a fiddle with the unobtrusive handler: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Edww3/

Comment: This seems to get the context correctly. I will attempt you use it and if it works well for me I will mark this as correct answer. I would still like to see if anyone else has some better html only logic versus using javascript though. Thanks

Comment: The main issue is that the content is not bound, so normal data-binds on them won't work. One other thought would be to use my plugin here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-delegatedEvents to do delegated event handling.  It would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6GPNH/

Comment: Yea that is a little cleaner. Just a lot of code to load compared to the other way you gave me, but I guess it depends how often I need to use this logic in other parts of my website. I guess I will experiment and see how things work out for me.